# Manejar servicios en angular desde componente

Tags: angular, servicio

**Servicio**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HerokuService {

  private REST_API_SERVER = " secret";
  private SIGNUP = "/signup";


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public register(user){
    // return this.http.post(this.REST_API_SERVER, user, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      this.http.post<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER+this.SIGNUP, user).subscribe({
        next: data => {
          console.log('data');
          console.log(data);
          return data;
        },
        error: error => {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(error);
            return error;
          }
    })
}
}
```

**Register component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HerokuService } from "../heroku.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Registro';
  user= {
    name:'aaaa',
    email:'aaa@gmail.com',
    password:'aaa',
    repeat_password:'aaa'
  };
  submited = false;

  constructor(
    private herokuService:HerokuService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }


  register(){
    this.submited = true;
    if (this.user.password === this.user.repeat_password) {
        let result = this.herokuService.register(this.user);

        console.log('result child compo');
        console.log(result);

    }
    else{
      alert('Error: Las contraseñas no coinciden !');
    }
    this.submited = false;
  }

}
```

Lo que pasa es que quiero manejar el resultado de la **peticion http** desde el componente hijo, en este caso en el **register.component**.

Aqui uso el servicio : `let result = this.herokuService.register(this.user);`, pero quiero controlar de alguna manera el response que recibo, pero el result del servicio desde el hijo es undefined por tanto no se como mostrar una cosa u otra para el usuario. **¿Como podria tener el result del service en el hijo y ya manejarlo a mi gusto?**

Answer (score 0):

El resultado de llamar al servicio es undefined por que no estás retornando ningun valor en esa función. el return que haces dentro del `Observable` no es el return de la funcion `register` del servicio es el return de la funcion anonima que pasa como parámetro de la suscripción del `Observable` para que funcione debes retornar una promesa o un observable , por ejemplo:

```
public register(user) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http
        .post<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER + this.SIGNUP, user)
        .subscribe({
            next: data => {
                resolve(data)
            },
            error: error => {
                reject(error)
            }
        })
})
```

}

y en el component.ts obtendrías el resultado con:

```
let result = await this.herokuService.register(this.user);
```

O También puedes retornar directamente el Observable del llamado http y suscribirte desde el component:

```
function register(user) {
return this.http.post<any>(this.REST_API_SERVER + this.SIGNUP, user);
```

}

y en el component.ts

```
this.herokuService.register(this.user).subscribe({
next: data => {
    resolve(data)
},
error: error => {
    reject(error)
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

La llamada a this.herokuService.register(this.user); es asyncrona esto quiere decir que la respuesta no la optendras linealmente.

```
this.herokuService.register(this.user).subscribe(result => {
  // La variable result creala globalmente
  this.result = result;
  console.log(result);
});
```

Si lo quieres hacer linealmente necesitarias convertir la funcion register() en `async` y utilizar un `await` en la llamda del Api.

```
async register () {
   let result = await this.herokuService.register(this.user).pipe(map(res => res));
}
```